# Foreign key necessary or not?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

Suppose that i have four tables:

```
 Table 1 - Users  - id, name
 Table 2 - Models - id, user_id, name
 Table 3 - Types  - id, user_id, name
 Table 4 - Cars   - id, user_id, model_id, brand_id
```

Technically I don´t need the column 'user_id' in table Cars.

Using the 'user_id' fk is a good pratice? Redundancy? Sure it makes easier to program...

Comment: Can you explain why there is a column user_id in Models and Types?

Comment: Need? It's like asking if you need a column `email` in `Users`—you need it if you want that information, you don't need it if you don't want it. We have no idea of what your data mean but you may a have users who're responsible for a given model, type or car... or not. Perhaps the problem is that `user_id` doesn't really explain what the role means (compare with e.g. `main_driver_user_id`).

Comment: A FK provides an index (for efficiency in `JOINs`) and a constraint (for data integrity).  You can make your own INDEXes; the constraint is to check errors that you will eventually eliminate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you don't really need is the column `user_id` in `Models` and `Types`.
A car Model and a car Type is not directly related to a user.
This design would make sense:

```
Table 1 - Users  - id, name
Table 2 - Models - id, name
Table 3 - Types  - id, name
Table 4 - Cars   - id, user_id, model_id, type_id
```

if each car is related to only 1 user, but if it can be related to more users then you need another table:

```
Table 1 - Users       - id, name
Table 2 - Models      - id, name
Table 3 - Types       - id, name
Table 4 - Cars        - id, model_id, type_id
Table 5 - CarsUsers   - car_id, user_id
```

Comment: Models, types and cars are all related to just one user.

Comment: Then why don't you use only 1 table for Users and 1 table with user_id, model_name, type_name and car_name? And if a user can be related to only 1 car, model and type why don't you have only 1 table with all the info?

Comment: I suggest that that is "over-normalization".  That is  there is not an adequate argument for having `model_id` and `type_id` instead of simple strings for them.